# Windows 2008 R2 Service bound to what port?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I installed a service, and I'd like to know what port it is bound to.
Is there a command that will tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `netstat -a -n -b` should reveal some useful information.  You will probably get more readable and useful results with a tool like [tcpview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx).